Predicting Hit Points Between Target and Projectile
I'm trying to make a target tracking algorithm with a set projectile and target speed. The hit point (which is where the weapon should be aimed to hit the target) has to be on the path of the target, as well as being this ratio of distances: bulletSpeed/targetSpeed = bulletDist/targetDist. I think these equations are correct but I might be wrong: Target Path: y - targetPos.y = (targetVelo.y / targetVelo.x) * (x - targetPos.x) Distance Equation: (targetPos.x - x)^2 = ((targetSpeed^2) * ((weaponPos.x - x)^2 + (weaponPos.y + y)^2) / bulletSpeed) - (targetPos.y - y)^2 Then the hit position(s) are the points that the line intersects the circle formed by the distance equation. Does somebody know the equation for the intersection of the distance function and the line/target path? Desmos Graph With Problem The difference between this question and the projectile motion question is that only the bullet speed is known and not the direction, the direction is what we are trying to find by calculating the intersection between the distance equation and the target path. Desmos graph showing the problem

Please use MathjJax

What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

This is the same question as the one you posted three days ago, word for word. You ask, "Does somebody know the equation for the intersection of the distance function and the line/target path?" Have you tried looking at the answers that were posted in 2015? If they're no good for you, show us what the difficulty is.

And by "show us" I mean edit the question. Making the math readable (see MathJax comment above) greatly increases the likelihood that someone will actually read your formulas.
